# Magento 2 Js optimization

Tags: magento2, optimization

I use bundle js in **magento2** now when i run command the error is comming

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'E:/projecct/tts-core-au-deveopment/pub/static/frontend/Sm/custom/en_AU/jquery-ui-modules/resizable.js'

Comment: did u find any solution for this @imtiazau

Comment: yes  fixed my issue

Comment: Can you Please post your answer?

Answer (score 1):

In build.js
add **'jquery-ui-modules': 'jquery/ui-modules',**
line code below
this **'tinycolor': 'jquery/spectrum/tinycolor',**

Comment: worked fine now.